# How do I reverse the order of this mysql table or its representation?

Tags: php, mysql

The function below is what I used to display the contents of a table called 'tw'.  It is in reverse order.  I need to change the order.

```
  public static function posts()
    {
    $obj = new view;
    $email =  $_SESSION['email'];
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw");
    while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      $date = date('M j \a\t g:i:s a', $a[time]);
      echo  "<div class=\"Bb2b\"><img class=\"a\" src=\"p/$a[email].jpg\" alt=\"\"/><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\">$a[fname] posted on $date</a><br/><p class=\"c\">$a[message]</p></div>";
      }
    }
```

Comment: SQL has no concept of "order", unless you impose it with a `ORDER BY` clause (or similar).

Comment: And remember to write `\`row\`` instead of `row`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query you could append `` ORDER BY `time` ASC `` or `` ORDER BY `time` DESC `` whichever suits your needs (time is a dummy name, I don't know your table structure) [time as being a column].

EX: `` SELECT * FROM `tw` ORDER BY `time` DESC ``

[More info on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ORDER BY statment in your mysql query

```
      SELECT  * FROM tw ORDER BY attribute DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `order by` in your SQL query:
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlorderby.html

```
SELECT * FROM `tw` ORDER BY `tw` DESC
```

should reverse it